# Do I really need to specify install-interface includes dependencies?

Tags: cmake, include, installation, include-path

In a package of mine, I currently have:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
target_include_directories(
    mylib
    PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}> # ***
)
```

and also:

```
install(
  TARGETS mylib
  EXPORT mylib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION  "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION  "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION  "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
  INCLUDES DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}" 
)

install(
  EXPORT mylib
  FILE "mylib-config.cmake"
  NAMESPACE mylib::
  DESTINATION "lib/cmake/mylib" )
```

and I notice that in the installed `config.cmake` file, I see the include directory *twice*:

```
set_target_properties(mylib::mylib PROPERTIES
  # etc. etc.
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
)
```

So, as an experiment, I dropped the line marked `***` above - and the config file now has the include directory only *once*.

So, is doing this safe? That is, Do I really not need to specify install-interface include directories if I install a target with the INCLUDES parameter? Or - am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation clearly states that **both** `target_include_directories` command with non-*PRIVATE* keyword and *INCLUDES DESTINATION* clause for `install` command populates [INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) property.

It is up to you which method to use.

Note, that same target can be installed several times. `target_include_directories` affects on **all** installations, but *INCLUDES DESTINATION* affects only on a **specific** installation.

---

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/install.html) for *INCLUDES DESTINATION* clause:

> This option specifies a list of directories which will be added to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` target property of the `<targets>` when exported by the `install(EXPORT)` command. If a relative path is specified, it is treated as relative to the `$<INSTALL_PREFIX>`.

[Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/target_include_directories.html) for `target_include_directories`:

> `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` items will populate the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `<target>`.

Comment: 1. But does documentation guarantee that build-interface directories get "translated" into install-interface directories, like they seem to be? 2. If a target can be installed several times to different places, doesn't that suggest that it's the install command is where we should specify the destination of include files?

Comment: 1. There is no translation from *build-interface* to *install-interface*. In the resulted config file you see *INSTALL_INTERFACE* only: `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR` variable contains `include/` and, because this is not an absolute path, it is prepended with install prefix. 2. Installing a target several times is quite a rare thing. I agree that preferring *INCLUDES DESTINATION* has some sense, as it allows to describe all installation-related things in the one place. But currently neither CMake documentation nor other "official" sources I know prefer one way to another.

Comment: But when I _remove_ the INSTALL_INTERFACE line, i.e. when supposedly there's only a dependence on a BUILD_INTERFACE dir, I still get the include directory in the `-config.cmake` file.

Comment: Hm, probably the config file takes include directory from some other source. CMake definitely doesn't use BUILD_INTERFACE for installing the target and definitely doesn't assume any relation between `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Comment: Ok, I just re-checked. CMake seems to take exactly the union of directories from the INSTALL_INTERFACE of the target and the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES of the install command, nothing else. So there is no translation, as you suggested.